# How to use GROUP BY command properly in Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, bigdata, google-bigquery

I got a few problems when trying to fetch only specific data. First I don't know how to create a sql query (current sql query I can grab only one user) so I can grab the data like this.

[image: screenshot 2015-11-23 17 43 21]

Second I want to grab 1 year data until current date. Below is my sql query done so far (I need to do it manual one by one).

```
SELECT type,  COUNT(*) FROM (
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([githubarchive:day.events_], 
    TIMESTAMP('2013-1-01'), 
    TIMESTAMP('2015-08-28')
  )) AS events
WHERE type IN ("CommitCommentEvent","CreateEvent","DeleteEvent","DeploymentEvent","DeploymentStatusEvent","DownloadEvent","FollowEvent",
"ForkEvent","ForkApplyEvent","GistEvent","GollumEvent","IssueCommentEvent","IssuesEvent","MemberEvent","MembershipEvent","PageBuildEvent",
"PublicEvent","PullRequestEvent","PullRequestReviewCommentEvent","PushEvent","ReleaseEvent","RepositoryEvent","StatusEvent","TeamAddEvent",
"WatchEvent") AND actor.login = "datomnurdin"
GROUP BY type;
```

Reference:

https://www.githubarchive.org/

https://github.com/igrigorik/githubarchive.org

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I want to create a sql query to generate the desired output above.

Comment: You already have a sql query. Could you specify what your problem with it is?

Comment: It looks like you need to "pivot" your data. First, change your query so that `actor.login` is in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, rather than `WHERE` clause. Then search for "How to Pivot in Big Query" (sorry, I don't know the syntax myself). Hth

Comment: @oulenz query above I can grab only one person. I want multiple persons.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin your query looks for ONE actor.login, that's why it only gives one.... remove that "and actor.login =" and instead add a group by by that parameter. Check my answer, it should be the query you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to properly pivot the data:

```
SELECT actor.login,
ifnull(sum(if(type='CommitCommentEvent',1,null)),0) as CommitCommentEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='CreateEvent',1,null)),0) as CreateEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='DeleteEvent',1,null)),0) as  DeleteEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='DeploymentEvent',1,null)),0) as  DeploymentEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='DeploymentStatusEvent',1,null)),0) as  DeploymentStatusEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='DownloadEvent',1,null)),0) as  DownloadEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='FollowEvent',1,null)),0) as  FollowEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='ForkEvent',1,null)),0) as  ForkEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='ForkApplyEvent',1,null)),0) as  ForkApplyEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='GistEvent',1,null)),0) as  GistEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='GollumEvent',1,null)),0) as  GollumEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='IssueCommentEvent',1,null)),0) as  IssueCommentEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='IssuesEvent',1,null)),0) as  IssuesEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='MemberEvent',1,null)),0) as  MemberEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='MembershipEvent',1,null)),0) as  MembershipEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='PageBuildEvent',1,null)),0) as  PageBuildEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='PublicEvent',1,null)),0) as  PublicEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='PullRequestEvent',1,null)),0) as  PullRequestEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='PullRequestReviewCommentEvent',1,null)),0) as  PullRequestReviewCommentEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='PushEvent',1,null)),0) as  PushEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='ReleaseEvent',1,null)),0) as  ReleaseEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='RepositoryEvent',1,null)),0) as  RepositoryEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='StatusEvent',1,null)),0) as  StatusEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='TeamAddEvent',1,null)),0) as  TeamAddEvent,
ifnull(sum(if(type='WatchEvent',1,null)),0) as  WatchEvent,
FROM (
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([githubarchive:day.events_], 
    DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "YEAR"),
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  )) AS events
WHERE type IN ("CommitCommentEvent","CreateEvent","DeleteEvent","DeploymentEvent","DeploymentStatusEvent","DownloadEvent","FollowEvent",
"ForkEvent","ForkApplyEvent","GistEvent","GollumEvent","IssueCommentEvent","IssuesEvent","MemberEvent","MembershipEvent","PageBuildEvent",
"PublicEvent","PullRequestEvent","PullRequestReviewCommentEvent","PushEvent","ReleaseEvent","RepositoryEvent","StatusEvent","TeamAddEvent",
"WatchEvent")
GROUP BY 1
limit 100
```

Comment: How I can grab 1 year data until current date and find only specific location ("Malaysia")? I almost there...

Comment: That should go into another question as I don't see any location data next to these. That's AFAIK is a privacy thing.

Comment: I see. how about the 'date' thing?